# Player appears in front of objects even if it's in the background

Tags: unity

I have a player in `Z=0` and a fence object that I want it to be in from of the player so I set it to `Z=1`, it's a 2D game but in the 3D view I can see that the fence is actually in front of the player but in the 2D view the player is displayed in front.

Here are a couple of screenshots.

3D view, fence in front of player:

[image]

2D view, player in front of fence:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the Inspector details for each object

Comment: How do you use transparency? Are both objects drawn by the same camera or different cameras? What happens if you inverse the z order?

Comment: Sounds like your not using sprite layers properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2D, a sprites Z coordinates mean almost nothing. They have what's called a layer and an order in said layer, see:

[image]

You need to set the fence's `Order in Layer` parameter value higher than the player. If the player is still rendered above the fence, their layers and render queues might be the problem.